# Android - Sending Message to Thread Incoming Handler

Tags: java, android, multithreading, android-service

I have a `Service` that starts a new `Thread` that handles network activity.  I have my `Activity`, `Service`, and `Thread` all in separate files.  I am trying to set up communication between them using a `Messenger` created by passing the `Messenger` an extended `Handler`.  I've figured out how to make the `Service` and `Activity` talk to each other fine, but I can't figure out how to give my `Service` a target to allow it to send messages to the separate `Thread`.

This is what I am trying now, but the message from `Service` to `Thread` is never sent...

**Service**

```
public class TCPSocketService extends Service {

    //Messengers
    private Messenger clientMessenger;
    private Messenger socketMessenger;

    //Message Incoming Handlers
    private Messenger clientIncomingHandler;
    private Messenger socketIncomingHandler;    

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        Log.d("Service", "TCPSocketService created");
        isConnected = false;
        clientIncomingHandler = new Messenger(new ClientToServiceIncomingHandler());
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return clientIncomingHandler.getBinder();
    }

    /*
     * Event Handlers for Messages received from Client
     */

    /**
     * Called when {@link Service} receives the HELLO message from Client
     * Registers {@link Messenger} that represents the Client's Incoming Message Handler
     * 
     * @param msg   {@link Message} object containing {@link Messenger} for responses
     */
    private void onHello(Message msg) {
        registerClient(msg.replyTo);
    }

    /**
     * Called when {@link Service} receives the START_THREAD message from Client
     * Initializes and starts a new {@link Thread} with {@link SocketThread} class
     */
    private void onStartThread() {
        socketThread = new SocketThread(ip, port);
        new Thread(socketThread).start();
        socketMessenger = new Messenger(new SocketToServiceIncomingHandler(socketThread.getLooper()));

        //Tell Client thread has started
        Message msg = Message.obtain();
        msg.what = Event.THREAD_STARTED;
        messageClient(msg);
    }

    /**
     * Called when {@link Service} receives the CONNECT message from Client
     * Sends the {@link Thread} a {@link Message} telling him to connect to server
     */
    private void onConnect() {
        Message msg = Message.obtain();
        msg.what = Event.CONNECT;
        msg.replyTo = socketMessenger;
        messageSocket(msg);        
    }   

    /*
     * Support functions
     */

    /**
     * 
     * @param client
     */
    private void registerClient(Messenger client) {
        clientMessenger = client;
        Message msg = Message.obtain();
        msg.what = Event.HELLO;
        messageClient(msg);
    }

    /**
     * 
     * @param msg
     */
    private void messageClient(Message msg) {
        try {
            clientMessenger.send(msg);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    /**
     * 
     * @param msg
     */
    private void messageSocket(Message msg) {
        try {
            socketMessenger.send(msg);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    /**
     * Incoming Handler for messages coming from Client
     */
    private class ClientToServiceIncomingHandler extends Handler {

        @Override
        public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
            switch(msg.what) {
                case Event.HELLO:
                    Log.d("Service", "Client said HELLO");
                    onHello(msg);
                    break;
                case Event.START_THREAD:
                    Log.d("Service", "Client said START_THREAD");
                    onStartThread();
                    break;
                case Event.CONNECT:
                    Log.d("Service", "Client said CONNECT");
                    onConnect();

                default:
                    Log.e("Service", "Client said some weird shit");
                    super.handleMessage(msg);
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * Incoming Handler for messages coming from Socket
     */
    private class SocketToServiceIncomingHandler extends Handler {

        public SocketToServiceIncomingHandler(Looper mainLooper) {
            super(mainLooper);
        }

        @Override
        public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
            switch (msg.what) {
                case Event.CONNECTED:
                    Log.d("Service", "Socket said CONNECTED");
                    onConnected();
                    break;
                case Event.DISCONNECTED:
                    Log.d("Service", "Socket said DISCONNECTED");
                    onDisconnected();
                    break;

                default:
                    super.handleMessage(msg);
            }
        }
    }   
}
```

**Thread**

```
public class SocketThread implements Runnable {

    //Properties
    private Handler serviceIncomingHandler;

    //Target to send Messages to Serivce
    private Messenger serviceMessenger;

    /* (non-Javadoc)
     * @see java.lang.Runnable#run()
     */
    @Override
    public void run() {
        Log.d("Socket", "New thread started...");       
        Looper.prepare();
        serviceIncomingHandler = new ServiceToSocketIncomingHandler();      
        Looper.loop();
    }

    /*
     * Event Handlers for Messages from Service
     */

    private void onConnect(Messenger serviceReplyTo) {
        serviceMessenger = serviceReplyTo;

        Message msg = Message.obtain();
        if (socket.isConnected()) {
            msg.what = Event.CONNECTED;
        } else {
            msg.what = Event.DISCONNECTED;
        }

        messageService(msg);
    }

    /*
     * Support methods
     */

    public Looper getLooper() {
        return Looper.getMainLooper();
    }

    public void stopLooper() {
        serviceIncomingHandler.getLooper().quit();
    }

    private void messageService(Message msg) {
        try {
            serviceMessenger.send(msg);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }   

    private class ServiceToSocketIncomingHandler extends Handler {

        @Override
        public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
            switch (msg.what) {
                case Event.CONNECT:
                    Log.d("Socket", "Service said CONNECT");
                    onConnect(msg.replyTo);
                    break;
                case Event.DISCONNECT:
                    Log.d("Socket", "Service said DISCONNECT");
                    onDisconnect();
                    break;
                case Event.NEW_PICTURE:
                    Log.d("Socket", "Service said NEW_PICTURE");
                    onNewPicture(msg.obj);
                    break;          

                default:
                    Log.e("Socket", "Service said some weird shit...");
                    super.handleMessage(msg);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**LogCat Ouput**

```
Client(451):    Binding to Service...
Service(451):   TCPSocketService created
Service(451):   Started...
Client(451):    Binded to service
Service(451):   Client said HELLO
Client(451):    Service said HELLO
Service(451):   Client said START_THREAD
Socket(451):    New thread started...
Client(451):    Service said THREAD_STARTED
Service(451):   Client said CONNECT
```

Is there anyway to accomplish getting the Thread's Incoming Handler target so that I can send Messages to them from my `Service` class?

Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to get this working by making my `SocketThread` class `extend Thread` instead of `implements Runnable`.  Then, I created a `Looper` object in the class and made a method in the `SocketThread` class that returned the `Looper` and one that returned the `Handler`.  This way, the `TCPSocketService` creates a `SocketThread` object, and asks for it's `Looper` and `Handler`, so it can start sending messages back and forth.

Comment: Can you update your code for the same please? I am stuck with a similar problem.

Answer (score 1):

Also you can extend `HandlerThread`.